# What does an `autocmd User` do?

Tags: autocmd, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-vim-plug

I switched to `vim-plug` recently. In [the README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md#on-demand-loading-of-plugins), there's this snippet for using YouCompleteMe with vim-plug:

```
" Code to execute when the plugin is loaded on demand
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'for': 'cpp' }
autocmd! User YouCompleteMe if !has('vim_starting') | call youcompleteme#Enable() | endif
```

What's the `autocmd` for?

According to [`:h User`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#User):

```
                                                        User
User                            Never executed automatically.  To be used for
                                autocommands that are only executed with
                                ":doautocmd".
```

So, apparently it's something I should run manually.

The actual configuration I used was:

```
" YCM command lifted from vim-plug readme
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': 'python2 ./install.py --clang-completer --gocode-completer --tern-completer', 'for': ['cpp', 'c', 'go', 'sh', 'js', 'vim'] }
autocmd! User YouCompleteMe if !has('vim_starting') | call youcompleteme#Enable() | endif
```

Now, for any of these filetypes, I don't need to run any command. YCM starts working as it normally used to, before I switched to `vim-plug`. Running `:doautocmd User YouCompleteMe` has no visible effect.

For anything else, `:doautocmd` just throws an error:

```
Error detected while processing User Auto commands for "YouCompleteMe":
E117: Unknown function: youcompleteme#Enable
```

So, it seems I can't use it for enabling YCM for other filetypes on-demand.

What's the point of that `autocmd`, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understanding, that example creates a `User` autocommand named `YouCompleteMe` which will be fired by `vim-plug` itself, in order to load the plugin on demand. If I'm not mistaken, here's the place where `vim-plug` will run the custom autocommand:

```
function! s:lod(names, types, ...)
  for name in a:names
    call s:remove_triggers(name)
    let s:loaded[name] = 1
  endfor
  call s:reorg_rtp()

  for name in a:names
    let rtp = s:rtp(g:plugs[name])
    for dir in a:types
      call s:source(rtp, dir.'/**/*.vim')
    endfor
    if a:0
      if !s:source(rtp, a:1) && !empty(s:glob(rtp, a:2))
        execute 'runtime' a:1
      endif
      call s:source(rtp, a:2)
    endif
    if exists('#User#'.name)
      execute 'doautocmd User' name        <<<< HERE <<<<<
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

Source code: [link](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/820cc6356962927a73193daaafda6484ca461e4a/plug.vim#L442)

So basically, the intended "user" of this autocmd is `vim-plug` itself.

Comment: Yep. It seems, for manual loading of YCM for other filetypes, I'll have to call [`plug#load('YouCompleteMe')` first](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#loading-plugins-manually).