# Can I get vim-plug to skip installing a plugin, based on some Vimscript condition?

Tags: plugin-vim-plug

I'm using vim-plug for managing plugins, primarily for its lazy-loading capabilities. This lets me do:

```
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': 'python2 ./install.py --clang-completer --gocode-completer --tern-completer', …}
```

I don't have YCM in all systems where I do have my `.vim` present and updated, and sometimes I'm not interested in having it present or installed - Supertab suffices for my needs in these cases, and installing YCM takes too much time, and YCM itself might be too heavyweight.

Now, I can skip the build step, since it is a shell command and I can probably do something like `'do': '[[ -z $INSTALL_YCM ]] && python2 …'`. Can I get vim-plug to skip cloning the YCM plugin altogether? It has a bunch of submodules (and submodules within submodules … it's turtles all the way down), and downloading all that would just be a waste of time and bandwidth.

---

YCM is just an example. As I add more plugins (I have 17 now, and as I understand, some users have twice as many), I would be interested in skipping plugins on systems where they have no use at all. So, don't focus on YCM.

Comment: Doesn't wrapping the Plug statement inside an if block work? I use it successfully with Vundle to decide on a certain plugin for neovim and vim.

Comment: @tokoyami since apparently other Vimscript commands in can affect it (http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6854/205), I'm a bit wary of using general Vimscript in the vim-plug block without knowing if it can affect vim-plug in other ways. It'd be nice if there were some vim-plug-sanctioned way.

Comment: You can use `if some_condition` in `vim-plug` blocks without problem.

Comment: @VanLaser so what parts of Vimscript do I need to be careful of  in the vim-plug block? I don't think `a, b` is regular Vim syntax for anything in command arguments, so just seeing the use of a `,` made me wonder at first - and then the `autocmd` bit made me more nervous.

Comment: I mean something like what you see in this picture: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4184/1800, but instead of using `executable`, you can check some other Vim or environmental variable (such as the host name).

Comment: @VanLaser It is rather straightforward, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can use Vimscript within the vim-plug block, so I ended up checking for particular commands to control installation of plugins. For example, I rarely have cmake installed, I usually install it for YCM. So a `executable('cmake')` check is good enough for that. Now, my vim-plug block has one section for common plugins, and a set of checks for those which are useful in specific cases:

```
call plug#begin()
" Common plugins
Plug 'vim-scripts/diffchar.vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tomasr/molokai'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'gabrielelana/vim-markdown', {'for': 'markdown'}
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar', {'for': ['cpp', 'c', 'go', 'sh', 'js']}
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'

if executable('cmake')
    " YCM command lifted from vim-plug readme
    Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': YCMInstallCmd(), 'for': ['cpp', 'c', 'go', 'sh', 'js', 'vim'] }
    autocmd! User YouCompleteMe if !has('vim_starting') | call youcompleteme#Enable() | endif
endif
if executable('go')
    Plug 'fatih/vim-go', {'for': 'go'}
endif
if executable('latex')
    Plug 'lervag/vimtex', {'for': 'tex'}
endif
if executable('ghc')
    Plug 'dag/vim2hs', {'for': 'hs'}
endif
if executable('man')
    Plug 'murukeshm/vim-manpager'
endif
if executable('dpkg')
    Plug 'vim-scripts/deb.vim'
endif
if executable('logrotate')
    Plug 'moon-musick/vim-logrotate'
endif
call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#conditional-activation) (prettier formatting there):

> #### Conditional activation
>
> Use plain "if" statement to conditionally activate plugins:
>
> ```
> if has('mac')
>   Plug 'junegunn/vim-xmark'
> endif
> ```
>
> The caveat is that when the condition is not met, `PlugClean` will try to remove the plugin. This can be problematic if you share the same configuration across terminal Vim, GVim, and Neovim.
>
> ```
> " When started with plain Vim, the plugin is not registered
> " and PlugClean will try to remove it
> if has('nvim')
>   Plug 'benekastah/neomake'
> endif
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can pass an empty `on` or `for` option so that the plugin is registered but not loaded by default depending on the condition.
>
> ```
> Plug 'benekastah/neomake', has('nvim') ? {} : { 'on': [] }
> ```
>
> A helper function can improve the readability.
>
> ```
> function! Cond(cond, ...)
>   let opts = get(a:000, 0, {})
>   return a:cond ? opts : extend(opts, { 'on': [], 'for': [] })
> endfunction
>
> " Looks better
> Plug 'benekastah/neomake', Cond(has('nvim'))
>
> " With other options
> Plug 'benekastah/neomake', Cond(has('nvim'), { 'on': 'Neomake' })
> ```